# problems connecting to mikrotik admin interface via router ip

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, mikrotik-routeros

All works fine ultil few days, now when i try to connect to 192.168.88.1 is giving me a connection refused error, internet works fine but can't connect to router admin interface, my router is "Mikrotik RB951 series" ... any suggestions?

Comment: Is your gateway 192.168.88.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a bug in Mikrotik box. Try rebooting it.